# RunningValue not matching between Group Footer and Tablix Footer

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report showing patients' height and weight, in imperial and metric units. I have the records grouped by PID, with a last static row in the tablix outside the groups. The dataset has four added calculated fields, for the four values I'm looking at. They're defined as `"if name='WEIGHT' then value else ''"`, and so forth. In both the footer and the last row, I have the expression

```
=RunningValue(Iif(Max(Fields!ObsValHeight.Value, "table1_PID") > "" 
            Or Max(Fields!ObsValHeightCM.Value, "table1_PID") > ""
        , Fields!PID.Value
        , Nothing
        )
    , CountDistinct
    , Nothing)
```

Unfortunately, the totals don't match. The distinct count of PID is 12893. The running total in the group footer shows 12100, but the expression in the tablix footer shows 12257. Can anyone explain the discrepancy without seeing the actual data? Thanks.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the aggregate functions, including RunningValue, do not operate on what you physically see in the rendered report but on the scope of the data that it represents at the group, data region, or table level. It sounds like you have different data in scope for your group and tablix - is there are filter involved anywhere perhaps?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no filters involved.

Comment: I'm afraid then the answer to your actual question is "No, at least not without more information"...

Comment: Kind of figured that, unfortunately. I was hoping that I had done something blatantly obvious with the scoping...